# How to open a Flutter .hive file from Hive in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

Can someone please explain how to open the .hive files generated by Flutter Hive when you create a Box and add to it?

Within my application, the files are stored as name.hive files.

I have tried opening them as JSON/XML/plain text but nothing seems to work, the contents are showing incorrectly

I am using Android Studio on Ubuntu

Just want to know how I can open the file and view the contents properly?

Comment: Hi, did you you found any solution? im in the same issue...

Comment: this issue has been mentioned here. https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/679

Answer (score 2):

The easier way would be to copy `.hive` file to your computer and drag it into [Hive Studio](https://studio.hivedb.dev/#/) window.

I wrote an [app](https://github.com/lomza/listview_cubit_hooks) and a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580) using Hive DB, where I describe this.

Comment: As there is no scroll to it we can't see the whole content of it and even there is no option to copy the content!

Answer (score 0):

An issue was opened for [this](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/679) and the answer is:

```
Hive uses a custom binary format for storing data which isn't supported by any existing editors or tools.
```

so you cannot actually open a box `.hive` file like you could do with JSON, XML...